# Are there any differences between SMD and THT inductors?

Tags: inductor, surface-mount

I wonder if there exist any differences in performance between chip-SMD (like 0805) inductors and THT inductors?

More specifically I need to solder 10 uH 0805 SMD inductor for my bias tee module (like [this](https://www.chipdip.ru/product/mlz2012m100ht000-10), sorry for Russian page). However I can't get it right now so I've decided to use [this](http://radioremont.com/product/drossel_0307_1_4w_100k_10_mkgn_/) temporarily.

I know that typical max power dissipation is 0.1 W for 0805 form-factor and 0.25 W for small THT inductors/resistors. But I'm unaware if there any other pitfalls exist which could mess my things up. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: The **datasheet** gives you all the required data. I'm sure you can find an SMD inductor that has worse performance than some THT inductor. I'm also sure that you can find a THT inductor that has a worse performance than an SMD inductor. So yes there are differences. What differences: see the datasheet.

Comment: In addition to what Bimpelrekkie said, SMD inductors have very low contact resistances and inductances since they don't have "long legs". Some THT inductors can have a contact inductance of a few nanoHenries which may be considered in very sensitive high-frequency applications.

Comment: I understand that datasheet is the primary source of any info but I want to know personal experience of engineers and hobbyists. For resistors it's pretty much obvious that they're interchangeable and I've worked with them a lot but I wonder of there are any pecularities in SMD/THT inductors

Comment: @RohatKılıç thank you for pointing that out. I think in my case (filtering AC from coax in bias tee module) it's not makes a lot of sense because basic inductance should be about 10 uH. Available inductors provide me ~20% of tolerance so few nH shouldn't play much role